# How to display instant output in gridview for every loop in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, sap-dotnet-connector

I am collecting the number of system details and their availability in grid view, using the FOR loop for doing the same. Do I have any option of updating grid once each loop completes (every iteration of FOR loop)?

`gvReport -> Grid View`, which am using here

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)

{
    RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(sapcfg);
    RfcDestination dest = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination(table.Rows[i]["host"].ToString() + "," + table.Rows[i]["SID"].ToString() + "," + table.Rows[i]["Client"].ToString() + "," + table.Rows[i]["InsNo"].ToString());

    if (dest != null)
    {
        result = true
        dest.Ping();
    }

    if (result == true) 
    {
        gvReport.Rows[i].Cells[1].BackColor = Color.Green;     
    }
}
```